# Unsimplified Fractions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-cell-format

How can I get Google Sheets to display fractions in the form I enter them, rather than in a simplified form? I'm trying to evaluate how a student did on a test, so I have one cell that reports the number of questions on the test (A1), another that has the number of questions answered correctly (B1), and a third that shows questions that the student ran out of time to answer (C1).

I've been trying to display this fraction as B1/(A1-C1), and I can get it as a fraction, but Sheets insists on simplifying it.

Comment: Examples please. Please show us exactly what you mean with *fraction* and *simplified form*. Do you mean *1/2* or *2/4* or *2/(5-1)* for the former? Do you mean decimals for the latter?

Answer (score 1):

- one of these may serve:

  ```
  =B2&"/"&(A2-C2)
  ```




  ```
  =B2&"/("&A2&"-"&C2&")"
  ```




  ```
  =TEXT(B2/(A2-C2), "#??/??")
  ```

[image]